# ConcurrentHashMap and its operations

Tags: java, collections, thread-safety

Suppose there is a `ConcurrentHashMap` and there are two threads.

If both threads are reading some data from the same bucket, then my understanding says that both can read that bucket concurrently, as CHM does not block reading operations.

But suppose one thread is writing (`put`) to a bucket. Then, can a second thread simultaneously read (`get`) from the same bucket or will the second thread have to wait for the `put` operation to complete?

If it were `Hashtable` then `get` will have to wait until the `put` operation is complete. But in case of CHM how it will behave?

Comment: I think it will have to wait until you have written to the hashmap as you might want to read what the thread is adding.

Comment: If the write operation is in progress then all other threads must wait.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no need for speculation. The [source code for ConcurrentHashMap](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b128/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java) is open, and anyone can read it. (This is JDK 8 build 128, the first JDK 8 release candidate.)

You should have no trouble understanding it, as it's only 6,300 lines long. :-) Actually, a good fraction of this is comments, and most of the code goes toward handling edge cases. The straightforward paths of get() and put() aren't terribly complicated and are only a few dozen lines of code.

Your understanding of read operations (get(), contains()) is correct; there is no blocking. Hashing to a bucket and searching within the bucket, if necessary, is straightforward, with no locking. Memory visibility is ensured by volatile reads. (At lines 622-623, the `val` and `next` fields of `Node` are volatile.) Read operations proceed concurrently with other reads and also with writes to the same bucket.

The policy for removing and replacing values is fairly straightforward in that the head of the bucket is locked while the bucket is being searched and modified. See the `synchronized` block at line 1117 of `replaceNode`. A `put` that adds to an existing bucket is similar; see the `synchronized` block at line 1027 of `putVal`. These operations will of course block other threads attempting to remove, replace, or add entries to this same bucket. If a value is in the midst of being replaced, a thread that is getting the value for this key will see either the old value or the new value, depending on whether the reading thread finds the node before or after the value is replaced by the writing thread.

There is a special case for putting the first element into a bucket. At lines 1018-1020, if `putVal` finds a bucket empty, it will create a new Node and CAS (compare-and-swap) it into place. If this succeeds, the operation is complete. If two threads are attempting to add nodes into the same bucket more-or-less simultaneously, the CAS for the first will succeed, and the CAS for the second will fail. But note that this code is within a for-loop (line 1014). The thread whose CAS has failed simply goes around the loop and retries. In fact, all the other write operations are within a loop. The general approach is that operations proceed optimistically but are checked for concurrent writers. If the optimistic attempt fails, the operation is retried and goes through a (possibly) different path based on the now updated state.

Answer (score 1):

Hi as Per my knowledge ConcurrentHashMap allows multiple readers to read concurrently without any blocking. This is achieved by partitioning Map into different parts based on concurrency level and locking only a portion of Map during updates. Default concurrency level is 16, and accordingly Map is divided into 16 part and each part is governed with different lock. This means, 16 thread can operate on Map simultaneously, until they are operating on different part of Map. This makes ConcurrentHashMap high performance despite keeping thread-safety intact.  Though, it comes with caveat. Since update operations like put(), remove(), putAll() or clear() is not synchronized, concurrent retrieval may not reflect most recent change on Map.

I hope this will help..

Answer (score 1):

This is from the JavaDocs of ConcurrentHashMap class:

"Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations holding upon their onset"

Answer (score 0):

In Hastable concurrent operations will lock the whole collection, but in ConcurrentHashMap only one bucket will be locked.

Answer (score 0):

From the doc:

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and adjustable
>   expected concurrency for updates. This class obeys the same functional
>   specification as Hashtable, and includes versions of methods
>   corresponding to each method of Hashtable. However, even though all
>   operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail
>   locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in
>   a way that prevents all access. **This class is fully interoperable with
>   Hashtable in programs that rely on its thread safety but not on its
>   synchronization details.**
>
> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may
>   overlap with update operations (including put and remove). **Retrievals
>   reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations
>   holding upon their onset.** For aggregate operations such as putAll and
>   clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only
>   some entries. Similarly, Iterators and Enumerations return elements
>   reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the
>   creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be
>   used by only one thread at a time.

So, you shouldn't expect operations to synchronize exactly as a Hashtable, but the same (series of) operation are threadsafe. The second highlighted sentence does not imply, but in my opinion strongly suggest, what is going on here: a `put` in progress, i.e. not finished, will not block a `get` - the `get` will simply not see the changes yet.

Although I have not worked myself through the whole CHM class, this piece of documentation supports my hypothesis (taken from OpenJDK 6)

```
static final class Segment<K,V> extends ReentrantLock implements Serializable {
    /*
     * Segments maintain a table of entry lists that are always
     * kept in a consistent state, so can be read (via volatile
     * reads of segments and tables) without locking.  This
     * requires replicating nodes when necessary during table
     * resizing, so the old lists can be traversed by readers
     * still using old version of table.
```

When an update is "complete" doesn't seem to be explicitly defined; generally as soon as the new bucket is linked into the list of buckets, I guess. CHM also makes heavy use of volatile fields to ensure that threads read the most recent buckets in the list.

Comment: `a put in progress, i.e. not finished, will not block a get - the get will simply not see the changes yet.`-So  you mean while one thread is using put() on CHM other can use get() on the same bucket but it will not see the changes made by put()?